# CSS Image parent P tag height remains zero

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

i have an CSS problem

CSS

```
img[align="left"] {
display: block;
float: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<p>
 <img class="alignleft wp-image-48 size-thumbnail" src="http://url.com/en/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/jamones-secando-150x150.jpg" alt="jamones-secando" width="150" height="150">
 <img class="alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-50" src="http://url.com/en/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/queso_curado-150x120.jpg" alt="queso_curado" width="150" height="120">
 <img class="alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-49" src="http://url.com/en/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/embutidos-150x150.jpg" alt="embutidos" width="150" height="150">
```

please check this url http://goo.gl/R0CgpR

There are 3 images alingned on single line around middle of page.

The parent P tag height remains zero. so the next paragraph is aligning right to the images.
so i have to manually put a dot on next 5 lines to get the next paragraph come right below the image.

is this something i can fix through CSS., rather than using dots ?

Comment: Since you are using float left to your images inside your `p` tag you need to clear float on your `after` pseudo of your `p` tag. Or use clear-fix div after your `p`. this will fix the issue

Comment: @Benjamin - i tried p:after clear:both ., still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add overflow:auto to the `<p>` that contains the images and remove all the `<p>.</p>`

```
<p style="text-align: center; overflow:auto">
     <img class="alignleft wp-image-48 size-thumbnail" src="http://poqueira.com/en/wp-     content/uploads/2013/08/jamones-secando-150x150.jpg" alt="jamones-secando" width="150" height="150">
     <img class="alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-50" src="http://poqueira.com/en/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/queso_curado-150x120.jpg" alt="queso_curado" width="150" height="120">
     <img class="alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-49" src="http://poqueira.com/en/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/embutidos-150x150.jpg" alt="embutidos" width="150" height="150">
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to your `p` element style

```
<p style="text-align: center; overflow:hidden">
     <img class="alignleft wp-image-48 size-thumbnail" src="http://poqueira.com/en/wp-     content/uploads/2013/08/jamones-secando-150x150.jpg" alt="jamones-secando" width="150" height="150">
     <img class="alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-50" src="http://poqueira.com/en/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/queso_curado-150x120.jpg" alt="queso_curado" width="150" height="120">
     <img class="alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-49" src="http://poqueira.com/en/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/embutidos-150x150.jpg" alt="embutidos" width="150" height="150">
</p>
```